# quering one to many relations in hibernate 3

Tags: hibernate, orm, spring-mvc

I have a one to many relationship in hibernate (1 User -> Many Clients). This is mapped in the database as 3 tables, User, Client and User_Client_Mapping.

When a user is logged in to my application, I want to - select clients specific to this user, who have either their birthdate or anniversary date today. The choice of birthdate/anniversary date will come from the logged in User.

Any pointers as to how can i achieve this using Hibernate 3?

I am able to select all clients corresponding to a specific user.
I am also able to select based on birthdate/anniv date from all clients (for all users)

However, I am not able to select clients for a specific user and then select specific clients based on birthdate/anniv date criteria.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're able to do both, just combine the two queries:

Select all clients of a user:

```
select c from User u inner join u.clients c 
where u.id = :id
```

Select all clients with a given birthDate:

```
select c from Client c 
where c.birthDate = :birthDate
```

Combination of both:

```
select c from User u inner join u.clients c 
where u.id = :id and c.birthDate = :birthDate
```